# Is it possible to use Imagemagick to build a composite image from multiple photos of a moving object?

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

I frequently have 10 photos taken from a tripod mounted camera of an object moving across the field of vision.

I know that I can painstakingly combine these in PhotoShop/Gimp to create one composite image showing the object 10 times in a single frame.

I feel that this should be programatically possible. By analysing the 10 photos, one can find what the steady-state background is and then overlay only the moving object from each photo on top of it?

And generally, if something's possible, it means someone much cleverer than me will have already done it!

I've read all the options on the `composite` functionality and can't see anything relevant there?  Google hasn't thrown up anything useful, but I may just not be seeing it.

Many thanks

Comment: I have done such a thing by hand (using frames from a video), but the right technique wasn't to extract the instances of the object from the background but to use vertical stripes, [each wide enough to contain one instance](http://i.imgur.com/7ExjrWP.jpg). This was a lot easier than the prerequisite realignment of the pictures (hand-held smartphone) but since you used a tripod you shouldn't even need this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by composite. You can append the images side by side. But I suspect you want the average of all 10 images. That would be in Imagemagick as follows. Assume you have them all in one folder and nothing else in the folder and that they are all JPGs. Then you can get the average of all of the them by changing directory to that directory and doing:

```
convert *.jpg -evaluate-sequence mean average.jpg
```

If on IM 7, change convert to magick.

Comment: Won't that tend to make the object faint because you will only see 1/10th of it? Maybe if the object is light, shoot against a black background and use `-evaluate-sequence max` or if it is dark, shoot against a light background and use `-evaluate-sequence min`. I used the former to merge some long-exposure star trails quite successfully:-)

Comment: If the images have the same intensity except for where the object is placed and the object is lighter than the background, then Mark is correct. The object will be darker, but you will see all the objects in one image, which should still be lighter than the background. Then you could threshold to see the path of the object. But since the OP has not provided any images, it is hard to know what they look like and so how to answer properly. Using -evaluate-sequence min or max, may work as Mark has suggested depending upon the contrast of the object vs background.

Comment: CONTINUED: It would be better to have one frame that had no object in it and use that with -compose minus or -compose divide to remove the background. See  http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#divide and http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#known_bgnd